# How to replace alloca in an implementation of execvp()?

Tags: c++, posix, exec, alloca

Take a look at the NetBSD implementation of `execvp` here:

http://cvsweb.netbsd.se/cgi-bin/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/gen/execvp.c?rev=1.30.16.2;content-type=text%2Fplain

Note the comment at line 130, in the special case for handling `ENOEXEC`:

```
/*
 * we can't use malloc here because, if we are doing
 * vfork+exec, it leaks memory in the parent.
 */
if ((memp = alloca((cnt + 2) * sizeof(*memp))) == NULL)
     goto done;
memp[0] = _PATH_BSHELL;
memp[1] = bp;
(void)memcpy(&memp[2], &argv[1], cnt * sizeof(*memp));
(void)execve(_PATH_BSHELL, __UNCONST(memp), environ);
goto done;
```

I am trying to port this implementation of `execvp` to standalone C++.  `alloca` is nonstandard so I want to avoid it.  (Actually the function I want is `execvpe` from FreeBSD, but this demonstrates the problem more clearly.)

I think I understand why it would leak memory if plain `malloc` was used - while the caller of `execvp` can execute code in the parent, the inner call to `execve` never returns so the function cannot free the `memp` pointer, and there's no way to get the pointer back to the caller.  However, I can't think of a way to replace `alloca` - it seems to be necessary magic to avoid this memory leak.  I have heard that C99 provides variable length arrays, which I cannot use sadly as the eventual target is C++.

Is it possible to replace this use of `alloca`?  If it's mandated to stay within C++/POSIX, is there an inevitable memory leak when using this algorithm?

Comment: You say this is a standalone C++ environment? Does it provide `vfork`? If it does not provide `vfork`, or if `vfork` is identical to `fork` in this environment, then you can call `malloc` or `new` without worrying about a memory leak. In `fork`ed children, nothing you do will modify the parent's memory.

Comment: Ah!  For some reason I assumed the comment applied to fork() as well.  As the environment does not provide vfork, this question is invalid!  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Rob I don't think it would be valid for something to just call fork instead of vfork, because vfork behaves differently than fork (one returns immediately, the other only after the new process calls exec or _exit).

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: As Michael has pointed out in the comments, what is written below really won't work in the real-world due to stack-relative addressing by an optimizing compiler.  Therefore a production-level `alloca` needs the help of the compiler to actually "work". But hopefully the code below could give some ideas about what's happening under the hood, and how a function like `alloca` might have worked if there were no stack-relative addressing optimizations to worry about.*

BTW, just in case you were stil curious about how you could make a simple version of `alloca` for yourself, since that function basically returns a pointer to allocated space on the stack, you can write a function in assembly that can properly manipulate the stack, and return a pointer you can use in the current scope of the caller (once the caller returns, the stack space pointer from this version of `alloca` is invalidated since the return from the caller cleans up the stack).

Assuming you're using some flavor of Linux on a x86_64 platform using the Unix 64-bit ABI, place the following inside a file called "my_alloca.s":

```
.section .text
.global my_alloca

my_alloca:
    movq (%rsp), %r11       # save the return address in temp register
    subq %rdi, %rsp         # allocate space on stack from first argument
    movq $0x10, %rax
    negq %rax
    andq %rax, %rsp         # align the stack to 16-byte boundary
    movq %rsp, %rax         # save address in return register
    pushq %r11              # push return address on stack
    ret                     # return back to caller
```

Then inside your C/C++ code module (i.e, your ".cpp" files), you can use it the following way:

```
extern my_alloca(unsigned int size);

void function()
{
    void* stack_allocation = my_alloca(BUFFERSIZE);
    //...do something with the allocated space

    return; //WARNING: stack_allocation will be invalid after return
}
```

You can compile "my_alloca.s" using `gcc -c my_alloca.s`.  This will give you a file named "my_alloca.o" that you can then use to link with your other object files using `gcc -o` or using `ld`.

The main "gotcha" that I could think of with this implementation is that you could crash or end up with undefined behavior if the compiler did not work by allocating space on the stack using an activation record and a stack base-pointer (i.e., the `RBP` pointer in x86_64), but rather explicitly allocated memory for each function call.  Then, since the compiler won't be aware of the memory we've allocated on the stack, when it cleans up the stack at the return of the caller and tries to jump back using what it believes is the caller's return address that was pushed on the stack at the beginning of the function call, it will jump to an instruction pointer that's pointing to no-wheres-ville and you'll most likely crash with a bus error or some type of access error since you'll be trying to execute code in a memory location you're not allowed to.

There's actually other dangerous things that could happen, such as if the compiler used stack-space to allocate the arguments (it shouldn't for this function per the Unix 64-bit ABI since there's only a single argument), as that would again cause a stack clean-up right after the function call, messing up the validity of the pointer. But with a function like `execvp()`, which won't return unless there's an error, this shouldn't be so much of an issue.

All-in-all, a function like this will be platform-dependent.

Comment: Your first "gotcha" is actually quite common in optimized builds - the compiler can avoid creating an `rbp` based stack frame and simple access stack-based locals using offsets from `rsp`. A user-written `alloca()` is quite dangerous - it really requires cooperation with the the compiler.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714692/alloca-implementation/714833#714833

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I figured there must have been some "help" from the compiler side for a full-proof `alloca`. There's too many points of failure when written in the style shown above without some control over how the compiler would assemble the caller function.  I did try to mitigate issues by aligning the stack and not doing a simple subtraction of the stack pointer, as well as follow the Unix ABI for function calls.  While it seemed to work fine with -O2 optimization, you're completely right -- even one instance of stack-relative addressing by the compiler will cause crashes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the call to `alloca` with a call to `malloc` made *before* the call to `vfork`.  After the `vfork` returns in the caller the memory can be deleted.  (This is safe because `vfork` will not return until `exec` has been called and the new program started.)  The caller can then free the memory it allocated with malloc.

This doesn't leak memory in the child because the `exec` call completely replaces the child image with the image of the parent process, implicitly releasing the memory that the forked process was holding.

Another possible solution is to switch to `fork` instead of `vfork`.  This will require a little extra code in the caller because `fork` returns before the `exec` call is complete so the caller will need to wait for it.  But once `forked` the new process could use `malloc` safely.  My understanding of `vfork` is it was basically a poor man's `fork` because `fork` was expensive in the days before kernels had copy-on-write pages.  Modern kernels implement `fork` very efficiently and there's no need resort to the somewhat dangerous `vfork`.