# What does alloca(0) do and return on various platforms?

Tags: portability, libc, alloca

Does `alloca()` returns  NULL if the size given is 0?

A quick search reveals that  `alloca(0)` force garbage collection in some cases! but I am mostly interested by return value.

thanks

Comment: Garbage collection in native code?

Comment: @wormsparty, could be - but I find it as strange as you :)

Comment: There's no garbage collection in C; the statement that it forces garbage collection makes no sense.

Comment: it depends what we call garbage collection. glibc malloc call sbrk some time to return memory to the system. Similarly, an allocator could do some heavier work to reorganize it's internal data structures, perhaps you could also call it garbage collection...

Comment: Sure, but `alloca` allocates on the stack by basically moving the stack pointer; it can check if the result is still in the stack size (usually 2MB), but I don't think it has anything to do with the heap's memory management.

Comment: I see the term 'garbage collection' used in this implementation, but I agree with wormsparty that at first glance, it's not clear what that might mean, and line 191 seems to show that it actually does nothing.

https://github.com/bnoordhuis/phode/blob/32d401c3/deps/libdrizzle/win32/alloca.c#L20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Linux man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca)

> **Conforming to**
>
> This function is not in POSIX.1-2001.
>
> **Notes**
>
> The alloca() function is machine- and compiler-dependent.

So alloca()ing 0 size elements is not legal but not defined

I don't have a specifical example of the return value when size=0. Please, take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/714692/778693) and "Notes on the GNU Version" at the first link

Answer (score 3):

The gcc-2.95 implementation of alloca allocates memory from the heap using malloc itself. In the context of that implementation alloca (0) is equivalent to: `free (/*all the memory that was allocated with alloca when the stack pointer was deaper*/)`.
Here's a quotation from a commentary in the alloca.c file of the gcc-2.95.

> The general concept of this implementation is to keep
>      track of all alloca-allocated blocks, and reclaim any
>      that are found to be deeper in the stack than the current
>      invocation.  This heuristic does not reclaim storage as
>      soon as it becomes invalid, but it will do so eventually.
>
> As a special case, alloca(0) reclaims storage without
>      allocating any.  It is a good idea to use alloca(0) in
>      your main control loop, etc. to force garbage collection.

By the way in this implementation alloca(0) returns NULL.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca), `alloca` will allocate memory on the stack, and it will either succeed, or make your program crash.

Now, for an allocation of 0 bytes, you should not bother about the returned value: since there are 0 byte, there is no space for you to write, and no matter if the pointer value returned is `0x1234` or NULL, the program should crash anyway.

Comment: To put that second paragraph more precisely: dereferencing the returned pointer would give undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also, regarding your first paragraph: the manpage doesn't say 'crash', it says undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, `_alloca(0);` [returns the stack pointer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130501-00/?p=4493) (with some fixed offset.) This may be necessary in some exceptional situations when C code needs to know the `RSP` CPU register from within an `x64` process (since inline assembly is not supported for 64-bit builds in Visual Studio.)

Keep in mind though, that calling `_alloca(0);` will allocate some memory on the stack, so make sure not to call it repeatedly in the same local scope, as otherwise that may deplete your stack and cause the `stack overflow` exception.

As a much better alternative, consider calling [`_AddressOfReturnAddress()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s975zw7k.aspx) intrinsic instead.